# d3.layout.stack() with 'wiggle' offset issue

Tags: javascript, layout, d3.js, offset, stream-graph

I wrote a function in d3 in order to create multiple plots showing different datasets in the sampe page.

I'm using streamgraph and stack layout, and I cannot understand why with the same code I can generate plots using as offset `zero`, `expand` and `silhouette` while using the same dataset and the same stack layout the `wiggle` offset does not produce anything.
(I already read more than once the documentation)

Herewith an excerpt of the code:

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .values(function(d) {
        return d.values;
    }).offset(o || 'silhouette');// o could be one of [expand, wiggle, zero, silhouette]

var layers = stack(stacked.datalayers()); // See after this piece of code

var maxY = d3.max(layers, function(c) {
    return d3.max(c.values, function(d) {
        return d.y0 + d.y;
    });
});

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(stacked.x()).rangeRoundBands([0, w]); // stacked.x() returns an array with the min and the max values for X
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxY]).range([h, 0]);

var area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) {
            return x(d.x) + (x.rangeBand() / 2);
        })
        .y0(function(d) {
            return y(d.y0);
        })
        .y1(function(d) {
            return y(d.y0 + d.y);
        }).interpolate("monotone");

...

series.append("path")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return area(d.values);
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(cdomain.indexOf(d.name));
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", ".5")
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return color(cdomain.indexOf(d.name));
        })
        .style("stroke-width", "2px");
```

This is the structure of the data as returned from `stacked.datalayer()`:

```
[
  {
    "name": "US",
    "values": [
      {
        "x": "01/2014",
        "y": 1.726118500604595,
        "name": "US",
        "y0": 0.8662854227545267
      },
      {
        "x": "02/2014",
        "y": 2.5897229845496037,
        "name": "US",
        "y0": 0.38969767845094694
      },
      {
        "x": "03/2014",
        "y": 2.388349800480026,
        "name": "US",
        "y0": 0.518912280793379
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Europe28",
    "values": [
      {
        "x": "01/2014",
        "y": 0.42541539123546496,
        "name": "Europe28",
        "y0": 2.5924039233591216
      },
      {
        "x": "02/2014",
        "y": 0.5149863958976154,
        "name": "Europe28",
        "y0": 2.9794206630005506
      },
      {
        "x": "03/2014",
        "y": 0.4579303752823291,
        "name": "Europe28",
        "y0": 2.907262081273405
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here are some screenshots of the results (using the same dataset):

offset 'zero':
[image: offset 'zero']

offset 'expanded':
[image: offset 'expanded']

offset 'silhouette':
[image: offset 'silhouette']

offset 'wiggle':
[image: offset 'wiggle']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for `stack.x`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout#x):

> The return value of the accessor must be a number.

The default accessor returns `d.x`, and your data currently contains strings for this property (e.g. `"01/2014"`).  You can either set your own accessor, or modify the data so that the x-value is a number.  The reason it only affected the `wiggle` mode is that it uses the x-value to compute the gradient.